Python and PIP Package Location
I have a dual PC setup at home where my main PC is running Ubuntu 24.04. This is where I do most of my python development. As an example, the yfinance package is installed and i run python programs located in $HOME/bin/python anywhere from the command line. (PATH includes bin/python and all .py files start with #!/usr/bin/env python).
I installed Ubuntu (WSL2) on my Win11 PC and when I tried to run a .py file developed on the Ubuntu machine I got warnings that the yfinance package wasn't installed. I tried to do a pip install of the package but got the following warning:
This environment is externally managed
╰─> To install Python packages system-wide, try apt install
    python3-xyz, where xyz is the package you are trying to
    install

Well, I did some digging around and created a venv at $HOME/.venv
Now, in order to execute the .py programs on the Win11 machine, I have to type
.venv/bin/python3 bin/python/tracker.py msft,1000,3.22

I also have to specify the full path to the .py file. It won't let me do
.venv/bin/python3 tracker.py sabr,1000,3.22

This is slightly confusing and very annoying.
Running
pip show yfinance

on the ubuntu machine shows that it's installed in
/home/user/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages

Further,
which python

on the ubuntu machine shows
/home/user/.local/bin/python

If I keep the .venv location on the win11 machine at $HOME/.venv, is there a way I can set up the environment so I don't have to type the long command form
.venv/bin/python3 bin/python/tracker.py msft,1000,3.22

What is best practice between how it's set up on my Ubuntu machine where (somehow) Python is installed i .local/bin and on the Win11 machine at /usr/bin/python3?

You might want to read up on virtual environments for Python. If you have two machines, you probably want two virtual environments and replicate your code into these two environments.
